# Solve non linear equation with one variable Python

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve the following equation in python with sympy.

13000*1.44**x =1000000

I tried:

```
x = symbols('x', real=True) 
print(solveset(Eq(130000*1.44**x, 1000000), x))
```

Now this does gives:

```
ConditionSet(x, Eq(1.44**x - 100/13, 0), Complexes)
```

Is this equation not suitable for solveset? Do I need to solve this with fsolve?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the docs ["Solveset is designed to be independent of the assumptions on the variable being solved for and instead, uses the domain argument to decide the solver to dispatch"](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#what-is-this-domain-argument-about). Try adding the `domain=` parameter like in the docs.

Comment: I would not use the `scipy` tag, since this is not related to SciPy at all.

Comment: Thanks I did at it because i thought maybe fsolve was needed. I removed the tag

Comment: thanks - wsdookadr  i added it in the comments under the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting this answer is because there are infinitely many solutions over the complex numbers. Assuming you just want real numbers, try using `solveset_real`:

```py
from sympy.solvers.solveset import solveset_real

x = symbols('x', real=True)
print(solveset_real(Eq(130000*1.44**x, 1000000), x))
```

gets you

```
FiniteSet(2.74240747387354*log(100/13))
```

Comment: Man thanks! I thought real=True  was enough, I did not know about the solveset_real option and did not read it on the sympy site . I am used to Matlab symbolic....

Comment: solveset(Eq(130000*1.44**x, 1000000), x, domain=S.Reals) I like this also. see comment @wsdookadr.

Comment: @matthijsW I suppose `solveset` ignores the symbol type (İ don't remember what `real=True` gets you honestly). You might raise this as an issue to the sympy devs and see what they have to say about it.